# Two different variables pointing to the same memory location

Tags: java, arrays, complex-data-types

I would like to use different variables to access the same data.

i.e. I have an array:

```
float[] vector = new float[3];
```

I would like each value in the array to also have its individual label i.e.:

```
vector[0] == pitch;
vector[1] == yaw;
vector[2] == roll;
```

I would like to use vector[] & pitch/yaw/roll interchangeably. When I pass all three values between two functions I want to refer to the array, however when I access them individually I would like to refer to them as pitch yaw and roll.

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: @ Lee Meador Yes, I tried what Jace J McPherson suggested, but as pointed out, that does not work.
@ Juvanis - I am of course aware of that option. However I was wondering if there where a 'less brute force' method of doing it, partly because it would be useful, partly 'academic interest'

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a primitive `float` and an array of type `float[]`. Java does not support variables that are pointers or references to primitives.

However, there are a few workarounds.

First, you could make your own mutable reference type holding a float value.

```
MyFloat[] vector = new MyFloat[3] { new MyFloat(p), new MyFloat(y), new MyFloat(r) };
MyFloat pitch = vector[0];
MyFloat yaw = vector[1];
MyFloat roll = vector[2];
```

But it would probably be better to wrap your array in an object, and use *methods* to get the members by meaningful name, rather than variables.

```
public class Orientation {
  private float[] vector = new float[3];

  public float[] getArray() { return vector; }

  public pitch() { return vector[0]; }
  public yaw() { return vector[1]; }
  public roll() { return vector[2]; }

  public setPitch( float pitch ) { vector[0] = pitch; }
  public setYaw( float yaw ) { vector[1] = yaw; }
  public setRoll( float roll ) { vector[3] = roll; }
}
```

This gets you close -- although you can't just say `pitch`, you could say `o.pitch()`.

Comment: Just noticed that Louis Wasserman had already suggested encapsulation. He should get the credit for that. I'm leaving this answer since it's filled out a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible the way you mean.  You can't set `pitch = 20` and get `vector[0] == 20`; primitives, at least, don't work that way in Java.  What you could do, though -- what you should do -- is create a class named `Vector` with methods named `setPitch`, `getPitch`, etc, and use the `float[3]` as an internal implementation detail.

Comment: yep. that makes sense. basically the same thing Andy Thomas is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a primitive data type in java only send a copy of its data to the requested method. If you are looking to pass a **Reference** to the value (rather than a copy), then you should use the Object form of the variables.

So, use `Float` in place of `float`. This will make your numbers Object variables rather than primitive data types.

Comment: -1: Even if you use `Float`, this won't be possible for two reasons: 1. `Float` object references (as other primitive wrapper classes) are **immutable**. 2. Java is **pass by value**, no matter what. Refer to [Is Java “pass-by-reference”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197).